# How to Set Meteor requestOfflineToken for Google OAuth

Tags: oauth, meteor

I am having trouble figuring out how to enable google offline mode inside of my meteor app.

I am currently using the account-google package for user authentication and the documentation for meteor states that offline mode is possible with google auth.

I am also using appcache for local storage of the app in the clients browser.

Everything is working flawlessly until I disconnect from the internet and then the google auth expires and I am unable to use my app.

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice

My problem is that I am having trouble figuring out where to call Meteor.loginWithGoogle({requestOfflineToken: true});

Any help or insight would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call that in the **client**, as it mentions in the documentation. Methods in the docs will say where you can use them to the far right of the method name.

That is, wherever you called it before when it was working.

Comment: I have never called it, I am using the default accounts-google package and would like to add offline support to it. When I call the function directly the app hangs.